# OneToMany does not return values saved from other entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have entity structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    List<UserAgreement> userAgreements= new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_agreements")
public class UserAgreement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agreement_id")
    private Agreement agreement;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "agreements")
public class Agreement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "agreement", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    List<UserAgreement> userAgreements = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I am using Spring Boot with JpaRepository. When I use `AgreementRepository extends JpaRepository<Agreement, Long>` to save Agreement and related UserAgreement, it works well and cascades necessary fields to DB:

```
agreement.getUserAgreements().add(new UserAgreement(user, agreement, status));
agreementRepository.save(agreement);
```

However, after save, if try to retrieve `user.getActiveUserAgreements()`, I get empty list. It does not refresh.

How to force User entity to get `List<UserAgreement>` which was saved from other side?

Comment: Add fetch type eager

Comment: Tried, does not help.

Comment: Can you check in the database whether this data is stored in the database or not?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wikibooks: OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)

> The relationship is bi-directional so, as the application updates one
>   side of the relationship, the other side should also get updated, and
>   be in sync. In JPA, as in Java in general it is the responsibility of
>   the application, or the object model to maintain relationships. If
>   your application adds to one side of a relationship, then it must add
>   to the other side.

That means you need to assign the `UserAgreement` to the `User` when you create the relation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like many-to-many association. You might probably drop UserAgreement class. Anyway, to support it you have to write helper methods addAgreement(), removeAgreement() etc. See more details here https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/